# Latest Facebook SDK not logged out from App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook

I have updated my latest Facebook SDK.

FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;

loginBehavior Doesn't work with that.
Now my app is not logging out every time it says

[image]

On click of cancel it doesn't give me any option to login with any other acc.

My Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 return  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

 #pragma mark-5.Facebook Button Click
- (IBAction)bnfacebookClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
        while (topController.presentedViewController) {
               topController = topController.presentedViewController;
            }


    NSArray * allViewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    NSLog(@"COntroller%@",allViewController);


    //Facebook Button click...
    txtEmailLogin.text = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(profileUpdated:) name:FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification object:nil];


      FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
           [login logOut];
            NSLog(@"TOken%@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]);
    [login logInWithPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
    {
               if (error)
               {
               } else if (result.isCancelled)
               {
               }
               else
               {
                   _fbRequesting = NO;


                   if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"public_profile"])
                   {
                       if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
                       {
                           [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"name, email, picture"}]
                            startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id user, NSError *error)
                            {
                                if (!error)
                                {
                                    ViewSignIn.hidden=false;
                                    [objappdelegate startActivityIndicator];
                                    typesocial=1;
                                    Userdetails=user;
                                    stremailidfinal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Userdetails valueForKey:@"email"]];
                                    [self SocialLoginSignup:Userdetails];

                                }
                            }];
                       }
                   }
               }
           }];
   // }

}
```

Can Somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

This is intended design. If you need to log in with a different account, you will need to log out of Facebook app and possibly also facebook.com in Safari from your mobile device.

The reason being that if you log out of an app, it should not log you out of Facebook as it violates user's expectations.

It's stated [here for Unity SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Logout#besties) but the same principle applies.

> Having a logout control inside a game that executes a Facebook-wide logout will violate users' expectations. Instead, allow users to control their logged-in status on Facebook itself.

Comment: there is no other way ?